# Trigger function on page load (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, which runs on click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('p.distance-units label input:radio').click(function() {
        var units = $(this).parents('label').attr('units');


        if ($(this).parents('label').hasClass('unchecked')) {
            changeDistanceUnits(units);
        }


    });
```

I would like it to be triggered on page load as well.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the `click` method:

```
$('p.distance-units label input:radio').click(function() {
  // ...
}).click();
```

Comment: It worked, but the values didn't update for some reason (like it does when you click it). How to add some delay to this construction? Thanks @undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use trigger to call initially 

 $('p.distance-units label input:radio').on("click",calBack);
     // Trigger
     $('p.distance-units label input:radio').trigger("click");

function calBack(){

            if ($(this).parents('label').hasClass('unchecked')) {
                changeDistanceUnits(units);
            }
    }
```

Comment: @Tim you can call the trigger event when you need

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('p.distance-units label input:radio').click(function() {
        var units = $(this).parents('label').attr('units');

        if ($(this).parents('label').hasClass('unchecked')) {
            changeDistanceUnits(units);
        }
    });

    $('p.distance-units label input:radio').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to trigger the click for only the checked items so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p.distance-units label input:radio').on('click',function () {
        var units = $(this).parents('label').attr('units');
        if ($(this).parents('label').hasClass('unchecked')) {
            changeDistanceUnits(units);
        }
    }).filter(':checked').triggerHandler('click');
});
```